# Want to Pre-set Radio buttons based on string

Tags: android, string, radio-button

Hi I am creating an edit page for a database and i want to

get the string ive passed over via intent

then depending on if the string is equal to "on" or "off"

i want to change the the selection of the radio button

so far i have this

```
radiogroup = R.id.radioGroup1;

if (switch.equals("on")){
    radiogroup.check(R.id.radio1);
    R.id.radio1.setChecked(true);
} else {
    radiogroup.check(R.id.radio0);
    R.id.radio1.setChecked(true);
}
```

btw this is in my oncreate as i want it to run as soon as the Activity is open

Comment: hello. how do i change the selection of the radio button based on the string

Comment: Am just getting red lines under all of the radio parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inflate your radio buttons, per example with

```
RadioButton radio1 = findViewById(R.id.radio1);
```

Then you can use

```
radio1.setChecked(true/false)
```

like you were trying.

Comment: Happy to help you :) Feel free to accept the answer when you're helped.

Comment: oh yeah sorry new to using this

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the `RadioButtons` like this:

`RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);`

after that you can call

`radio1.setChecked(true);` or `radio1.setChecked(false);`